# ASP.Net mvc , getting error on publishing a web project , set as release

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, release

i want to publish a web project , while on publishing it with release, i got an error shown below

```
 Copying file lib\jquery-validation\build\release.js to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\lib\jquery-validation\build\release.js failed. 
Could not find a part of the path 'lib\jquery-validation\build\release.js'. MyProject.Web 0
```

Comment: I bet that your `csproj` file has an incorrect path

Comment: which path? can you explain more? @MariaInesParnisari

Comment: From where i can give it path?

Answer (score 0):

The error is right in front of you. Your project can't find `lib\jquery-validation\build\release.js`. Ensure the file exists.

Comment: file doesn't exist. how create that file?